# How to stop Microsoft Word from opening file in readonly mode

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

When I open a file from a network folder, Word always opens it in readonly mode.
 How to stop Office from doing this. I want it to just open it as normal and I don't need office to do any security procedures.

Any idea how I can get this resolved?

Answer (score 10):

1. Run the Office 2010 application with the problem. Notice that this procedure has to be done individually with each of the applications in MS Office suite (great!).
2. Click on the Office button on the upper left-hand corner and select “Options”
3. In the “Options” dialogue box, select “Trust Center” (on the left)
4. Click on “Trust Center Settings” (on the right)
5. Select “Protected View”
6. Disable any of all the protected view options by unticking the check boxes.
7. Click OK when done.

[From http://quantumtunnel.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/microsoft-office-2010-issue-with-opening-files-as-read-only](http://quantumtunnel.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/microsoft-office-2010-issue-with-opening-files-as-read-only/)

P.S. Do you have write permissions?

Comment: i've done this but it still opens in readonly mode

Comment: Just noting that the above is 100% correct, but Lynne Okazaki's tip to disable "open e-mail attachments" under General options screen was also needed to solve my specific issue -- opening files from email when Word was closed prior to opening the emailed file.

Answer (score 6):

Go into Word Options there's a check box under Start up options:  Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view.  Uncheck the box and click OK.  This should remove the readonly.

Answer (score 1):

If the file was downloaded from the internet then *right click on the file > Properties* and then ***unblock*** it

[image: unblock file]

If the file was opened directly from a network drive then check the file's permissions

Comment: my file is on network folder

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off the Preview Pane and Details Pane in the File Open dialog box from within the Office application.  If you are opening the files directly from Windows Explorer, try turning off the Preview Pane in Windows Explorer as well.

There seems to be an issue with the Preview Pane issuing a temporary lock on the file in order to preview its contents.  If the file is opened while this lock is in place, it will open in read-only mode.  The problem is worse with larger files over slower network connections.

For more information, and other possible solutions/workarounds, visit [The Definitive 'Locked File' Post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/05/14/the-definitive-locked-file-post.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I just went to file properties, and applied Read Only, and after that removed again (click apply to take effect). After that, the file started to open correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried everything else and it's still opening as Read-Only despite that box not being checked in the properties. Close all instances of MS Word and try again. That was the only thing that ended up working for me.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_windows8-mso_365hp/word-always-opens-documents-in-read-only-mode/cd04e338-a1c3-49b9-ae8c-a1119aca1c6f) solved my problem, I think best is to try disabling the add-in, they may cause word to be opened in safe more, at least this happened in my case. Please read @DanielJackson's answer in that post.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the case for anyone else, as I have tried and failed several times using the above suggestions.
Only to realise that I opened the file which was in a compressed folder...
You might want to check that.

Comment: That should not cause the document to be opened read-only.

Answer (score 1):

After dedicating hours of my life to trying every one of the above suggestions, I found the problem was not 'read-only' mode, but 'read' mode!

All I had to do was click on print layout (the open book icon) in the Status Bar on the footer of a Word page.  Now feeling rather foolish; but am not too proud to tell the story in case others may be affected by the same (hopefully) temporary dumbness.

But thanks to all of the above contributors for their clear explanations.  I have learned from them.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had an Excel Add In (Asap Utilities) installed. I re-installed it and the problem (after a few minutes of opening, the files already opened in Excel became 'Read Only) seems to have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered this problem with Microsoft Excel. The error message was saying the problem comes from the sharing options. Lo and behold, when I right-clicked my problematic excel file, clicked on share with,and then clicked on my username, the problem has disappeared. Now I can happily modify and save my file. I have just found this solution so now I just hope it lasts through windows explorer/computer restart. I hope this simple solution works for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Word >>> File
2. In the “Options” dialogue box, select “Trust Center” (on the left)
3. Click on “Trust Center Settings” (on the right)
   THEN "Trusted Locations"
4. Where do you store your files? Add your file directories to the 'Trusted Locations' List

MicroSoft has default locations to store your files. If you store your data elsewhere on your PC or Network, then add the directories to "Trusted Locations' List so that your files do not open as protected.

Keep all internet and Outlook attachment files protected under the "protected view" section

Answer (score 0):

If word opens as 'read only' close it and go to task manager by alt + ctrl+dlt. then you will find a winword file under process even you close your word file. end this winword and re open your word file and it is not read only. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My antivirus (Avast) tricked me into accepting some sort of ransomware shield feature which took it upon itself to lock a bunch of my folders including My Documents.  This caused the Read Only disaster.  I went into Avast|Protection|RansomwareShield and disabled the whole stupid shield (which was also blocking -- er...protecting -- My Photos and a bunch of other folders).  MS Word worked fine after that.

Comment: Sorry that happened to you… But… What is this? This question is about stopping Microsoft Word from opening a file in read only mode? What does that have two do Avast making your files and directories read only?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was cured by turning off the 'auto save' feature ... Why? Who knows, but it worked.